# Combine Unix Test Commands && + ||

Tags: linux, string, unix, testing, ksh

KSH - HP-SOL-Lin
Needs to be POSIX

I want to test if multiple conditions are true, then do something.

Assumptions:

- `FIELDS=0`
- `$STRING=''` or `$STRING=' '`

Right now I have:

```
if [[ $FIELDS -ne 0 && ! -z $STRING ]]; do
```

This works fine, if `$STRING` is null, but sometimes it has a single space. How can I make process the two `$STRING` tests first? Conceptually, I would like equivalent of:

```
[[ $FIELDS -ne 0 && [ ! -z $STRING || $STRING = ' ' ]  ]]
```

Comment: Using `[[` causes unspecified results.  If you want to be POSIX, you must use `[` or `test`.

Comment: @WilliamPursell `[[` doesn't cause unspecified results. Non-POSIX-compatible results or non-portable results, yes, but `bash` or `ksh` or `zsh` or whatever shell it's being done in do specify what the results are.

Comment: @twalberg Quoting from the standard:  `The following words may be recognized as reserved words on some implementations (when none of the characters are quoted), causing unspecified results:
[[ ]] function select`

Comment: @WilliamPursell Ok, so unspecified as far as the POSIX standard is concerned, but not unspecified in general. I can write a perfectly functional and fully specified `bash` script that just happens to contain some elements that the POSIX standard considers "unspecified results".

Comment: @twalberg.  The definition of unspecified is that the standard does not specify the behavior.  The questioner specifically requests POSIX conformance, which is not possible if using syntax whose behavior is unspecified by the standard.  Yes, several shells recognize the syntax, but, *in general*, the behavior is unspecified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can separate the tests:

```
if [[ $FIELDS -ne 0  ]]; then
  if [[ ! -z $STRING || $STRING == ' ' ]]; then
    do some stuff
  fi
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

For POSIX conformance,

```
if [ "$FIELDS" -ne 0 -a  ( ! -z "$STRING" -o "$STRING" = " " ) ]; then
...
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Bearing in mind that $STRING can be a single space, I'm assuming that the value it is set to (between null and space) is irrelevant, in which case an easier way would be to run a simple check on $STRING first:

```
if [[ $STRING == ' ' ]]
then
    export STRING=''
fi

if [[ $FIELDS -ne 0 && ! -z $STRING ]]; do
```

Improves readability and means you won't have to execute the same additional tests for subsequent commands.

If my assumptions are incorrect please don't hesitate to send me to the naughty step.